# Meteor Iron-Router force page refresh

Tags: javascript, meteor, refresh, router, iron-router

I just recently started working with *Meteor* and *Iron Router*, so I'm having some issues.

I am looking to have a very basic website and am nearly there but when it comes to reusing one of the templates for various directories, the page doesn't refresh which causes it to show the previous page despite the URL showing the correct page.

Once I hit refresh on the browser then the page will actually reload with the correct page, but I would rather not have to always refresh the page and **would like to simply just have to click on a link and get the correct information**.

I have attempted some of the solutions that I have seen pertaining to similar issues, but they all seemed to be a bit more unique than mine. I have included my `.js` file from *meteor*.

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('iotprofiler');
});

Router.route('index.html', function () {
  this.render('iotprofiler');
});

Router.route('/device(.*)', function () {
  //document.location.reload(true);
  this.render('profile');

});


if(Meteor.isClient){
    //this code only runs on the client

    var directory = Iron.Location.get().path;
    var start = directory.lastIndexOf("/");
    var stop = directory.search(".html");
    var parseddir = directory.slice(start + 1,stop);
    console.log(parseddir);

    Template.iotprofiler.helpers({
        'device': function(){
            return DeviceList.find();
        }
    });

    Template.profile.helpers({
        'iotdevice': function(){
            return DeviceList.find({model: parseddir});
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `parseddir` is not [reactive](http://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/).

A solution is to follow the doc [rendering template with data](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#rendering-templates-with-data) for iron router.
Just give `parseddir` as data to the `profile` template when you render it and in your helper use `this.parseddir` to get the actual data.